# Android: how to make CheckBox not selectable?

Tags: android, checkbox

On Android, how do I make a CheckBox that is active but not selectable? I want to disallow the user to change the checked not checked state.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> On Android, how do I make a CheckBox that is active but not
>   selectable? I want to disallow the user to change the checked not
>   checked state.

You could subclass `Checkbox` and force `setChecked` always to `true`. E.g.

```
public class AlwaysCheckedCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox {

    public AlwaysCheckedCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

and reference it to your layout

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will leave open more time to see if someone gives a less invasive answer... but thanks!